# indexOf and includes in the background - JS

Tags: javascript

I do wonder how `indexOf` and `includes` work in the background.

They work like loops which checks the whole array if an element is in what index or if it exists. Are they actually looping in the background?

Also, if someone could provide resources about topics like this, that would be great. I tried searching in google and existing posts here but to no avail. My search terms might not be good.

#### EDIT:

I am trying to do a comparison test and almost always, `includes` is faster when identifying if a blank cell is present.

The issue is this difference in time that does show negative number randomly.

```
function myFunction() {
  array = [1, 2, 3, "", 5];
  var t0 = new Date().getMilliseconds();
  j=0
  while(j<10000000) {
    x = array.indexOf("") > -1;
    j++;
  }
  var t1 = new Date().getMilliseconds();
  console.log(`Call to indexOf took ${t1 - t0} milliseconds.`);

  i=0;
  var t2 = new Date().getMilliseconds();
  while(i<10000000) {
    y = array.includes("")
    i++;
  }
  var t3 = new Date().getMilliseconds();
  console.log(`Call to includes took ${t3 - t2} milliseconds.`);
}
```

Why does this happen?
[image]

Tested in google apps script

Comment: See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) regarding testing execution time. You'll have to test it on arrays with tens of thousands of items at least, though.

Comment: Thanks for this.. I've been seeing performance tests here but not sure where they got that. @ISAE

Comment: Interesting.  I think something must be getting cached by the runtime between the two loops.  Try allocating a second array and looping it on the second test.

Comment: @danh, same issue. got it when i added array2 containing the same elements. maybe just  because i was running the function fast repeatedly?

Comment: It's not always @danh. It just happens i think around 1 in 10 or more runs.

Comment: So many global variables.

Comment: @epascarello, my bad. I just tried to separate them each as I'm not sure if redefining the same variable would actually use more time or not. So to be fair with the comparison, I used different variables with same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getMilliseconds is the milliseconds at the current time. It is not the total milliseconds.

```
Time 1: 1 minute 300 milliseconds
Time 2: 2 minutes 100 milliseconds

100 - 300 = -200
```

You want to use something like [performance.now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)

```
const t1 = performance.now();
// some process
const t2 = performance.now();
console.log(t2-t1);
```

or just subtracting two dates

```
const t1 = Date.now()
// some process
const t2 = Date.now();
console.log(t2-t1);
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense with the negative millisecond result.

Comment: I tried performance on google apps script and it seems that it isn't available. so I might use getTime instead. **EDIT**, `getTime` works